# What is a 'clean' way of getting the output required?

Tags: query

I need to aggregate the total for when the `case when` statement returns true. But I need to do this per partition. My data looks something like this:

```
Product|Variation_code|Total_product_variations|Discount_code
A      | x21          |          3             |     OFF
A      | x22          |          3             |     LIQ
A      | x23          |          3             |     NON
B      | x4           |          2             |     LIQ
B      | x9           |          2             |     LIQ
C      | x34          |          4             |     
C      | X36          |          4             |     OFF
C      | x39          |          4             |     NON
C      | x37          |          4             |     OFF
```

I want the total count per product where Discount_code = 'LIQ'

I have tried `CASE WHEN(Discount_code = 'LIQ' then 1 else 0 end) AS total_liq` but it returns 1 or 0 in each row.

Similarly, `COUNT(CASE WHEN Discount_code  = 'LIQ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS total_liq` returns a bunch of single 1's like so:

```
Product|Variation_code|Total_product_variations|Discount_code | total_liq
A      | x21          |          3             |     LIQ      |    1     
A      | x22          |          3             |     LIQ      |    1
```

There is a group by 1,2,3,4,5 at the end of each of these. How do I go about achieving this?

I can't roll variation_code into product or filter as I need to be able to see them later.

Comment: Please tag the qiestion with the rdms and version you are using

Comment: Could you please provide your table structures as DDL and your data as DML? It's unclear to me exactly what you want - you only have one listing for each product - so what's the point of doing `COUNT`s or `SUM`ming?

Comment: What is meant by `Total`? Are you looking for the total variations or row counts or something else?

Comment: And please add your current query which you are referring to